# Extract year from pandas datetime column as numeric value with NaN for empty cells instead of NaT

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, na

I want to extract the year from a datetime column into a new 'yyyy'-column AND I want the missing values (NaT) to be displayed as 'NaN', so the datetime-dtype of the new column should be changed I guess but there I'm stuck..

**Initial df:**

```
        Date  ID
0 2016-01-01  12
1 2015-01-01  96
2        NaT  20
3 2018-01-01  73
4 2017-01-01  84
5        NaT  26
6 2013-01-01  87
7 2016-01-01  64
8 2019-01-01  11
9 2014-01-01  34
```

**Desired df:**

```
        Date  ID  yyyy
0 2016-01-01  12  2016
1 2015-01-01  96  2015
2        NaT  20   NaN
3 2018-01-01  73  2018
4 2017-01-01  84  2017
5        NaT  26   NaN
6 2013-01-01  87  2013
7 2016-01-01  64  2016
8 2019-01-01  11  2019
9 2014-01-01  34  2014
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np  

# example df
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [12,96,20,73,84,26,87,64,11,34],     
                 "Date": ['2016-01-01', '2015-01-01', np.nan, '2018-01-01', '2017-01-01', np.nan, '2013-01-01', '2016-01-01', '2019-01-01', '2014-01-01']})  

df.ID = pd.to_numeric(df.ID)
 df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date) print(df)

#extraction of year from date
df['yyyy'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.strftime('%Y')  

#Try to set NaT to NaN or datetime to numeric, PROBLEM: empty cells keep 'NaT'
df.loc[(df['yyyy'].isna()), 'yyyy'] = np.nan     #(try1)
df.yyyy = df.Date.astype(float)                 #(try2)
df.yyyy = pd.to_numeric(df.Date)                #(try3)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) with converting to integers with [`Int64`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)

df['yyyy'] = df.Date.dt.year.astype('Int64')
print (df)
   ID       Date  yyyy
0  12 2016-01-01  2016
1  96 2015-01-01  2015
2  20        NaT  <NA>
3  73 2018-01-01  2018
4  84 2017-01-01  2017
5  26        NaT  <NA>
6  87 2013-01-01  2013
7  64 2016-01-01  2016
8  11 2019-01-01  2019
9  34 2014-01-01  2014
```

With no convert floats to integers:

```
df['yyyy'] = df.Date.dt.year
print (df)
   ID       Date    yyyy
0  12 2016-01-01  2016.0
1  96 2015-01-01  2015.0
2  20        NaT     NaN
3  73 2018-01-01  2018.0
4  84 2017-01-01  2017.0
5  26        NaT     NaN
6  87 2013-01-01  2013.0
7  64 2016-01-01  2016.0
8  11 2019-01-01  2019.0
9  34 2014-01-01  2014.0
```

Your solution convert `NaT` to strings `NaT`, so is possible use `replace`.
Btw, in last versions of pandas `replace` is not necessary, it working correctly.

```
df['yyyy'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.strftime('%Y').replace('NaT', np.nan)
```

Answer (score 2):

Isn't it:

```
df['yyyy'] = df.Date.dt.year
```

Output:

```
        Date  ID    yyyy
0 2016-01-01  12  2016.0
1 2015-01-01  96  2015.0
2        NaT  20     NaN
3 2018-01-01  73  2018.0
4 2017-01-01  84  2017.0
5        NaT  26     NaN
6 2013-01-01  87  2013.0
7 2016-01-01  64  2016.0
8 2019-01-01  11  2019.0
9 2014-01-01  34  2014.0
```

For pandas 0.24.2+, you can use `Int64` data type for nullable integers:

```
df['yyyy'] = df.Date.dt.year.astype('Int64')
```

which gives:

```
        Date  ID  yyyy
0 2016-01-01  12  2016
1 2015-01-01  96  2015
2        NaT  20  <NA>
3 2018-01-01  73  2018
4 2017-01-01  84  2017
5        NaT  26  <NA>
6 2013-01-01  87  2013
7 2016-01-01  64  2016
8 2019-01-01  11  2019
9 2014-01-01  34  2014
```